# Condição lógica em um dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Após encontrar um valor de um cálculo eu preciso comparar se esse valor é igual a algum da primeira coluna da tabela abaixo (percentil), caso seja igual, será selecionado o valor correspondente porém ao da segunda coluna (valores). E se não for igual, tenho que fazer uma interpolação entre os dois valores mais próximos ao qual ele se encontra.

Por exemplo: encontrei o valor igual a 0.1 e vou comparar com a primeira coluna da tabela e nesse caso, o valor correspondente a ele na segunda coluna seria 0.0158. Mas se o valor fosse 0.93, eu teria que fazer a interpolação entre 2.706 e 3.841 que são os valores correspondentes a 0.90 e 0.95.

A tabela é a seguinte:

```
tabelaq <- data.frame(percentil=c(0.005,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.975,0.99,0.995), 
  valores=c(0.0000393,0.000157,0.000982,0.00393,0.0158, 0.102,1.323,2.706,3.841,5.024,6.635,7.879))
```

Eu tentei condições lógicas com for e if, mas está dando erro. Tentei `subset(tabelaq,percentil==t, select = valores)` dentro de `if` e não deu.

Estou tentando no R.

Alguém pode me sugerir uma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função abaixo resolve o problema. Ela está comentada, mas basicamente ela testa se `x` está em `percentil`. Se estiver, apenas encontra o valor correspondente. Se `x` não está em `percentil`, ela encontra em qual intervalo `x` está e interpola os valores desejados.

Na falta de maiores instruções, acabei fazendo uma interpolação linear entre os valores, ou seja, tirei a média aritmética entre eles.

```r
tabelaq <- data.frame(percentil=c(0.005,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.75,0.90,
                                0.95,0.975,0.99,0.995), 
                      valores=c(0.0000393,0.000157,0.000982,0.00393,0.0158, 
                                0.102,1.323,2.706,3.841,5.024,6.635,7.879))


funcao <- function(x, tabela){

  # procura se x estah nos percentis
  
  if (x %in% tabela[, 1]) {
    
    # em caso positivo, retorna o valor correspondente
    valor <- tabela[tabela[, 1] == x, 2]
  } else {
    
    # em caso negativo, encontra o intervalo em que x estah
    # e faz a interpolacao em seguida
    indice <- findInterval(x, tabelaq$percentil)
    valor  <- (tabela[indice, 2] + tabela[indice+1, 2])/2
  }
  
  # testa se o resultado esta dentro de algum intervalo fora das caudas
  # se nao estiver, retorna NA
  if (length(valor) == 0) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(valor)
  }
  
}

funcao(0.1, tabelaq)
#> [1] 0.0158
funcao(0.93, tabelaq)
#> [1] 3.2735
funcao(0.000001, tabelaq)
#> [1] NA
funcao(0.999999, tabelaq)
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Nossa, me salvou demais. Deus te abençoe! Em relação à interpolação, eu pensei na função approx, ela realiza a interpolação linear, daí ficaria assim approx(tabelaq[,1]l,tabelaq[,2], xout=0.9875). xout é o valor de x a ser interpolado que no caso seria o x (xout=x). Gratidão!